# How to convert selenium python file to exe?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to convert python file to exe file. I've used pyinstaller.

Steps I followed:

I opened the cmd in the folder where is my script
I used the next command: pyinstaller --onefile -w name.py
And I got the below error when I want to open exe. I want to mention that I use selenium to open a Chrome Browser so chromedriver.exe is needed

Comment: Please add the error you received.

Comment: Are Chrome and Chromedriver installed on the running Host?? also with the compatible version(selenium - googlechrome - chromedriver??